# Angular-5-Typescript files ,codes display on server

Tags: angular, typescript, security

I had build My project and uploaded it to nginx server. 
But, .ts files and codes are being displaying in webpack folder.

How can i solve this problem. 
https://ibb.co/gHwEEe

Comment: Thank you. i was using "ng build" command. and upload dist folder

Comment: use -- prod for production env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Angular projects production environments, you will need to create a production build of your project which will create some files in "dist" folder, these files will be uploaded on server, not the development code. 
To make a build use the cmd : `ng build --prod`